# Android - Crashlytics doesn't log errors app wide, only activity it was initialized in

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've been having trouble with Crashlytics ever since I installed it into our app.  I can't get it to report crashes app wide.

The initial install suggested we add the start command *Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());* in the base application we had extended.   When I put it here, it wouldn't report on any crash, anywhere in the app.

I then moved it to our sign in activity, and while it would report crashes I trigger there, it would not report in any other activity.

I've moved it to two other activities and I get the same results.  It only reports where I initialize it, and only works if i initialize it once (I can't initialize it in each activity)

I emailed their support, and they basically said, that's not how it should behave, and that was essentially it, no suggestions or anything and I've received no further responses from them.  How helpful.

I've used it before in my other apps and it works fine, so I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong here?

This is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
}

}
android {

defaultConfig {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
}

productFlavors {

    flavorone{
        applicationId "ca.flavorone"
        manifestPlaceholders = xxxx

    }

    flavortwo{
        applicationId "ca.flavortwo"
        manifestPlaceholders = xxxx

    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ben,

Mike from Fabric here - very odd to hear about your experience with our support team. The init should be in your application's subclass if you have onCreate() there. Are you using multiple processes or do you have any other exception handlers installed?

Comment: Hi Mike, there was a custom exception handler in a base activity that someone had written awhile ago.  It didn't even occur to me that it'd conflict.   Everything is working fine now that I've removed it.  Many thanks!!!!

Comment: If you put that as the answer I'll mark it for ya.

Comment: Awesome to hear Ben, happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here - very odd to hear about your experience with our support team. The init should be in your application's subclass if you have onCreate() there. Are you using multiple processes or do you have any other exception handlers installed? If so, remove the other exception handlers and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Issue was a custom exception handler.

Comment: What was the other exception handler? I am having this same problem and already tried to disable parse crash reporting but it had no effect. Was it parse that you disabled and things started working?

Comment: Hi Mike, What if i have multiprocess? Do i need to follow any other steps??

Comment: @SivakumarS multiple processes or multiple threads? Just want to be sure.

Comment: I'm running a background service in separate private 'process'. And currently i'm initializing another instance of fabric in my service. Am i doing it right?

Comment: If you have multiple different processes, then you initialize Fabric on each instance. This isn't officially supported however.

Comment: Im trying to workaround so i can get crash logs to the dashboard for a service on different process, Is this supported atm? Is there any interest on implementing it on a near future? @MikeBonnell

Comment: There is no official support for it currently, but should work in most cases. It's not on our immediate roadmap to add in.

Comment: Hi mike i am initialising in Applicaton, subclass  oncreate but its not reporting any issue but if i initialise it in my BaseAvtivity on Create it instantly starts reporting crashes.. Help!

Comment: More information would be needed, but I'd recommend taking a look here to confirm everything is setup correctly: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is initializing Fabric separately in the process e.g if your separate process has a service add this in your onCreate() method:

`Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics())`